# How to Insert new contacts with values?

Tags: android

I want to insert a new contact with star flag , but it works well if I do not use start put code ? why ?

```
public void Contact_AddNewContact(ItemValue... items) {

        ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();

        ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
                .newInsert(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, null)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, null)
                .build());

        Builder cop = ContentProviderOperation
                .newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
                .withValue(
                        ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);

        ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
                .newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                **.withValue(
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.STARRED,
                        true)**
                .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
                .withValue(
                        ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
                        "9484651684651")
                .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE)
                .build());

        ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
                .newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
                .withValue(
                        ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                .build());

        cop.withValue(
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME,
                "Ali");

        ops.add(cop.build());
        try {
            getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    }
```

**.withValue(
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.STARRED,
                        true)**

Where is problem , why I got this problem with BOLD code but nothing without that code ?

thanks .

Answer (score 2):

This code is running succesfully in my apps. I think it will help you.

```
ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();
            ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
                    .newInsert(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, null)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, null)
                    .build());
            ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
                    .newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                    .withValueBackReference(
                            ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
                    .withValue(
                            ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                    .withValue(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME,
                            GetStoreList.get(m).get(0).toString()).build());
            ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
                    .newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                    .withValueBackReference(
                            ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
                    .withValue(
                            ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
                            GetStoreList.get(m).get(2).toString())
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_HOME)
                    .build());

            ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
                    .newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                    .withValueBackReference(
                            ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
                    .withValue(
                            ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
                            GetStoreList.get(m).get(3).toString())
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE)
                    .build());

            ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
                    .newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                    .withValueBackReference(
                            ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
                    .withValue(
                            ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
                            GetStoreList.get(m).get(4).toString())
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_WORK)
                    .build());

            ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
                    .newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                    .withValueBackReference(
                            ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
                    .withValue(
                            ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
                            GetStoreList.get(m).get(5).toString())
                    .withValue(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_FAX_WORK)
                    .build());

            ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
                    .newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                    .withValueBackReference(
                            ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
                    .withValue(
                            ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
                            GetStoreList.get(m).get(6).toString())
                    .withValue(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_FAX_HOME)
                    .build());

            ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
                    .newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                    .withValueBackReference(
                            ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
                    .withValue(
                            ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
                            GetStoreList.get(m).get(7).toString())
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_PAGER)
                    .build());

            ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
                    .newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                    .withValueBackReference(
                            ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
                    .withValue(
                            ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
                            GetStoreList.get(m).get(8).toString())
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_OTHER)
                    .build());

            ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
                    .newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                    .withValueBackReference(
                            ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
                    .withValue(
                            ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
                            GetStoreList.get(m).get(9).toString())
                    .withValue(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_CALLBACK)
                    .build());

            ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
                    .newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                    .withValueBackReference(
                            ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
                    .withValue(
                            ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
                            GetStoreList.get(m).get(10).toString())
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_CAR)
                    .build());

            ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
                    .newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                    .withValueBackReference(
                            ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
                    .withValue(
                            ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
                            GetStoreList.get(m).get(11).toString())
                    .withValue(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_COMPANY_MAIN)
                    .build());

            ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
                    .newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                    .withValueBackReference(
                            ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
                    .withValue(
                            ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
                            GetStoreList.get(m).get(12).toString())
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_ISDN)
                    .build());

            ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
                    .newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                    .withValueBackReference(
                            ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
                    .withValue(
                            ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
                            GetStoreList.get(m).get(13).toString())
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MAIN)
                    .build());

            ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
                    .newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                    .withValueBackReference(
                            ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
                    .withValue(
                            ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
                            GetStoreList.get(m).get(14).toString())
                    .withValue(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_OTHER_FAX)
                    .build());

            ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
                    .newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                    .withValueBackReference(
                            ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
                    .withValue(
                            ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
                            GetStoreList.get(m).get(15).toString())
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_RADIO)
                    .build());

            ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
                    .newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                    .withValueBackReference(
                            ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
                    .withValue(
                            ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
                            GetStoreList.get(m).get(16).toString())
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_TELEX)
                    .build());

            ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
                    .newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                    .withValueBackReference(
                            ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
                    .withValue(
                            ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
                            GetStoreList.get(m).get(17).toString())
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_TTY_TDD)
                    .build());

            ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
                    .newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                    .withValueBackReference(
                            ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
                    .withValue(
                            ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
                            GetStoreList.get(m).get(18).toString())
                    .withValue(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_WORK_MOBILE)
                    .build());

            ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
                    .newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                    .withValueBackReference(
                            ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
                    .withValue(
                            ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
                            GetStoreList.get(m).get(19).toString())
                    .withValue(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_WORK_PAGER)
                    .build());

            ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
                    .newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                    .withValueBackReference(
                            ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
                    .withValue(
                            ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
                            GetStoreList.get(m).get(20).toString())
                    .withValue(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_ASSISTANT)
                    .build());

            ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
                    .newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                    .withValueBackReference(
                            ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
                    .withValue(
                            ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
                            GetStoreList.get(m).get(21).toString())
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MMS)
                    .build());

            ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
                    .newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                    .withValueBackReference(
                            ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
                    .withValue(
                            ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                    .withValue(
                            Data.MIMETYPE,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA,
                            GetStoreList.get(m).get(22).toString())
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE_HOME)
                    .build());

            ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
                    .newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                    .withValueBackReference(
                            ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
                    .withValue(
                            ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                    .withValue(
                            Data.MIMETYPE,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA,
                            GetStoreList.get(m).get(23).toString())
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE_WORK)
                    .build());

            ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
                    .newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                    .withValueBackReference(
                            ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
                    .withValue(
                            ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                    .withValue(
                            Data.MIMETYPE,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA,
                            GetStoreList.get(m).get(24).toString())
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE_OTHER)
                    .build());

            ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
                    .newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                    .withValueBackReference(
                            ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
                    .withValue(
                            ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                    .withValue(
                            Data.MIMETYPE,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA,
                            GetStoreList.get(m).get(25).toString())
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE_MOBILE)
                    .build());

            ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
                    .newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                    .withValueBackReference(
                            ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
                    .withValue(
                            ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                    .withValue(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.STREET,
                            GetStoreList.get(m).get(26).toString())
                    .withValue(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.TYPE,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.TYPE_HOME)
                    .withValue(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.POBOX,
                            GetStoreList.get(m).get(27).toString())
                    .withValue(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.TYPE,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.TYPE_HOME)
                    .withValue(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.NEIGHBORHOOD,
                            GetStoreList.get(m).get(28).toString())
                    .withValue(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.TYPE,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.TYPE_HOME)
                    .withValue(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CITY,
                            GetStoreList.get(m).get(29).toString())
                    .withValue(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.TYPE,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.TYPE_HOME)
                    .withValue(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.REGION,
                            GetStoreList.get(m).get(30).toString())
                    .withValue(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.TYPE,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.TYPE_HOME)
                    .withValue(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.POSTCODE,
                            GetStoreList.get(m).get(31).toString())
                    .withValue(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.TYPE,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.TYPE_HOME)
                    .withValue(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.COUNTRY,
                            GetStoreList.get(m).get(32).toString())
                    .withValue(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.TYPE,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.TYPE_HOME)
                    .build());

            ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
                    .newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                    .withValueBackReference(
                            ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
                    .withValue(
                            ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                    .withValue(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.STREET,
                            GetStoreList.get(m).get(33).toString())
                    .withValue(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.TYPE,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.TYPE_WORK)
                    .withValue(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.POBOX,
                            GetStoreList.get(m).get(34).toString())
                    .withValue(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.TYPE,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.TYPE_WORK)
                    .withValue(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.NEIGHBORHOOD,
                            GetStoreList.get(m).get(35).toString())
                    .withValue(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.TYPE,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.TYPE_WORK)
                    .withValue(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CITY,
                            GetStoreList.get(m).get(36).toString())
                    .withValue(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.TYPE,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.TYPE_WORK)
                    .withValue(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.REGION,
                            GetStoreList.get(m).get(37).toString())
                    .withValue(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.TYPE,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.TYPE_WORK)
                    .withValue(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.POSTCODE,
                            GetStoreList.get(m).get(38).toString())
                    .withValue(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.TYPE,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.TYPE_WORK)
                    .withValue(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.COUNTRY,
                            GetStoreList.get(m).get(39).toString())
                    .withValue(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.TYPE,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.TYPE_WORK)
                    .build());

            ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
                    .newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                    .withValueBackReference(
                            ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
                    .withValue(
                            ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                    .withValue(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.STREET,
                            GetStoreList.get(m).get(40).toString())
                    .withValue(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.TYPE,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.TYPE_OTHER)
                    .withValue(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.POBOX,
                            GetStoreList.get(m).get(41).toString())
                    .withValue(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.TYPE,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.TYPE_OTHER)
                    .withValue(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.NEIGHBORHOOD,
                            GetStoreList.get(m).get(42).toString())
                    .withValue(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.TYPE,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.TYPE_OTHER)
                    .withValue(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CITY,
                            GetStoreList.get(m).get(43).toString())
                    .withValue(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.TYPE,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.TYPE_OTHER)
                    .withValue(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.REGION,
                            GetStoreList.get(m).get(44).toString())
                    .withValue(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.TYPE,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.TYPE_OTHER)
                    .withValue(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.POSTCODE,
                            GetStoreList.get(m).get(45).toString())
                    .withValue(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.TYPE,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.TYPE_OTHER)
                    .withValue(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.COUNTRY,
                            GetStoreList.get(m).get(46).toString())
                    .withValue(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.TYPE,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.TYPE_OTHER)
                    .build());
            // Log.e("insert",""+GetStoreList.get(l).get(0).toString());
            try {
                getContentResolver()
                        .applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // Log.e("Error", e.toString());
            }
```

Comment: How to get last inserted contact id. Please give me the code for that

Answer (score 0):

```
      public void Contact_AddNewContact(ItemValue... items) {

    ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();

    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
    //putting it here worked on mine  
            .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.STARRED,true)

            .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, null)
            .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, null)
            .build());
```